# Compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1' shows error

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I want to use firebse-ui , when i add compile  `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'` , it shows error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0
```

I had install Android 7.1.1 API level 25  , it can't help

What should i do fix this error ?  Thanks in advance.

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation) github to install their library correctly.

For your current situation the issue been resolved and you only need to change

`compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'`

to

`compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'`

Also, make sure that your Project gradle looks something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        //The repair for your issue with twitter
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's best to know what your really want from this library in order to not over size your application by adding libraries you don't need

Comment: thanks for your responding , i had checked it , Firebase/Play Services Version:10.0.0 or 10.0.1    , i use FirebaseUI Version:1.0.1   , i  try 1.1.1 too , it's still dosen't work

Comment: @徐博俊 did you try `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'`

Comment: yes i try 1.2.0 too , show error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0

Comment: @徐博俊 please check that your project gradle is something close to whats above

Comment: thank you ,i add maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
   It works !  But what is relationship about twitter...?  Why if i compile fires-ui that i have to maven url  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue in there is. But that was the suggestion in their github

Answer (score 0):

Check also which version match your Firebase vision on the table defined here [FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies), and change the source of maven repository in your project gradle from **mavenLocal()** to

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
```

this is resolve my problem